# How do you use ranges with Python HTTP Get Requests?

Tags: python, python-requests

Normally python get requests let you enter in parameters for HTTP Get Requests

```
import requests 

params={"lang":'en'}

response = requests.get(url, params)

print(json.loads(response.text))

{'text': 'Hello World', 'lang': 'en', 'time': '2019-04-04', 'id': 1608}
```

But for the time field I'd like to filter by a time range. Something like params = {"time": [2019-01-01, 2019-02-02] . Can this be done in parameters itself? If not how would it make sense to do it?

Comment: Well what does the API you're calling expect?

Comment: I'm not sure I entirely understand what this means. Are you saying I can only filter by range if the URL API explicitly has a range feature?

Comment: You can pass anything you want as parameters. Of course, the actual URL endpoint has to be aware of those parameters existing and have logic to handle them. So, the truth is there's no way to give you an answer since we have no idea what URL you're using or what parameters it accepts. If you want to find out if a date filter exists, you could always capture the network traffic of a legitimate request and see if there's a date range being sent. Of course you could always filter the output by time and date once you get it, assuming there's no supported parameters for filtering by date.

Comment: The answer to your question `Are you saying I can only filter by range if the URL API explicitly has a range feature? ` is YES!  The HTTP protocol never interprets what you put in the query parameters in a HTTP request.  It is up to the server on the other side to do something with them.

Comment: @Steve oh well that really sucks. Is there an easy way to do it from post processing the request?

Comment: @knowads check if there's a time in the returned value of the request, then add it to a list if it's in the range you want, discard it otherwise. That's a very basic thing in Python though that's certainly already been asked about here (getting a date/time string from an object and comparing to it).

Comment: Yes, of course there is.  You can do anything you want with the data you get back from a HTTP request.  It seems like @Wasif Hasan has given you one way to do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `datetime` module like this:

```
import requests 
import datetime 

params={"lang":'en'}
response = requests.get(url, params)
r = json.loads(response.text)
rTime = datetime.strprtime(r['time'], '%Y-%m-%d')
# !!ATTENTION!!
startDate = datetime.date(YEAR, MONTH, DAY)
endDate = datetime.date(YEAR, MONTH, DAY)
if rTime >= startDate and rTime <= endDate:
  # DATE IN RANGE
```